# Any difference between File.ReadAllText() and using a StreamReader to read file contents?

Tags: c#

At first I used a `StreamReader` to read text from a file:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dialog.OpenFile());
txtEditor.Text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

but found out about `File.ReadAllText` which seems to simplify my code to 1 line. Are there are any differences between the two? When should I use one over the other?

```
txtEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(dialog.FileName);
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are no differences if you are using the `ReadToEnd()` method. The difference is if you are using the `ReadLine()` method for large files as you are not loading the whole file into memory but rather allows you to process it in chunks.

So use `File.ReadAllText()` instead of `ReadToEnd()` as it makes your code shorter and more readable. It also takes care of properly disposing resources as you might forget doing with a `StreamReader` (as you did in your snippet).

Answer (score 35):

Looking at the code within mscorlib, File.ReadAllText actually calls StreamReader.ReadToEnd internally!

```
[SecurityCritical]
private static string InternalReadAllText(string path, Encoding encoding, bool checkHost)
{
    string result;
    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path, encoding, true, StreamReader.DefaultBufferSize, checkHost))
    {
        result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

If you use `ReadToEnd`, they are the same.  Otherwise, using the `StreamReader` allows you to read bytes at a time, do some computation with them, and then throw them away as needed.  For example, if you had a file containing a list of 2,000 numbers, and you wanted to add them together, you could:

- Call `File.ReadAllText` to read everything into a string and then parse through that string to compute the sum.
- *Or* you could create a `StreamReader` and read a few bytes at a time, computing the sum as you go.

The major difference between these two approaches is the transient memory usage.  After you have the sum, you can always throw all the intermediate data away.  In the `File.ReadAllText` approach, at some point you had the entire file contents in memory, while with the `StreamReader` approach, you only had a few bytes worth of file contents in memory at any one time.  This can be an issue depending on the size of your files and the kind of computation you're doing.

`File.ReadAllText` is convenient and quick.  `StreamReader` is powerful but more work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `File.ReadAllText` to read an unmanaged logging file (control by fstream), call `File.ReadAllText`, there will have `IO.Exception`:

> The file is control by another process

You must to use StreamReader `ReadToEnd` to replace it.