# C# Loading text data into WPF control

Tags: c#, wpf, file

I am searching for a very fast way of loading text content from a 1GB text file into a WPF control (`ListView` for example). I want to load the content within **2 seconds**.

Reading the content line by line takes to long, so I think reading it as bytes will be faster. So far I have:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead = 0;
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
    while((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
        Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
    }
}
```

Is there any way of transforming the bytes into string lines and add those to a ListView/ListBox?

Is this the fastest way of loading file content into a WPF GUI control? There are various applications that can load file content from a 1GB file within 1 second.

**EDIT:** will it help by using multiple threads reading the file? For example:

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //read content/load into GUI...
});
```

**EDIT 2:** I am planning to use **pagination/paging** as suggested below, but when I want to scroll down or up, the file content has to be read **again** to get to the place that is being displayed.. so I would like to use:

```
fs.Seek(bytePosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

but would that be faster than reading line by line, in multiple threads? Example:

```
long fileLength = fs.Length;
long halfFile = (fileLength / 2);
FileStream fs2 = fs;
byte[] buffer2 = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead2 = 0;
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    while((bytesRead += fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) < (halfFile -1)) {
        Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer);
        //convert bytes into string lines...
    }
});

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    fs2.Seek(halfFile, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    while((bytesRead2 += fs2.Read(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length)) < (fileLength)) {
        Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer2);
        //convert bytes into string lines...
    }
});
```

Comment: if you have such a big file, consider create a index file descript file offset and length of each lines, then you can load all text on demand with in miliseconds

Comment: @Sakura What do you mean? That I should read each line (apprx 2 million) and get the length of each line?

Comment: I mean if your file is not change frequently, you can create `one time` index file for it, then when you need you use this index file. A `12 megabytes` file can store information about offset and length of your 2 milions line.

Comment: Hmm the file changes often because various processes are writing data to it.

Comment: Althought your file updated often, if you only append text to the end of file you still use this way. In case you change at random position, consider @Tyress answer, it really fast when read line by line

Comment: I don't think it will be able to load the content within 1 second.

Comment: Yes, you're right, and we usually (always) avoid to load such big data to memory. And trust me, you will very lucky if you can load 1 milion items to ListView, unless you use some `virtual` loading. Let try.

Answer (score 1):

Using a thread won't make it *any faster* (technically there is a slight expense to threads so loading may take slightly longer) though it may make your app *more responsive*.  I don't know if `File.ReadAllText()` is any faster?

Where you will have a problem though is *data binding*.  If say you after loading your 1GB file from a worker thread (regardless of technique),  you will now have 1GB worth of lines to databind to your `ListView/ListBox`.  I recommend  you **don't** loop around adding line by line to your control via say an `ObservableCollection`.

Instead, consider having the worker thread **append batches of items** to your UI thread where it can append the items to the ListView/ListBox per item in the batch.

This will cut down on the overhead of `Invoke` as it floods the UI message pump.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to read this fast I suggest using the System.IO.File class for your WPF desktop application.

```
        MyText = File.ReadAllText("myFile.txt", Encoding.Unicode); // If you want to read as is
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("myFile.txt", Encoding.Unicode); // If you want to place each line of text into an array
```

Together with DataBinding, your WPF application should be able to read the text file and display it on the UI fast.

About performance, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545407/3881866).

> So use File.ReadAllText() instead of ReadToEnd() as it makes your code
>   shorter and more readable. It also takes care of properly disposing
>   resources as you might forget doing with a StreamReader (as you did in
>   your snippet). - Darin Dimitrov

Also, you must consider the specs of the machine that will run your application.

Comment: `ReadAllLines` loads the entire content into an array. That is not efficient because it takes to long and loading everything into memory is not recommended, I have tried that. And I have a `using() {..}` statement that automatically disposes of the FileStream object..

Comment: You can take a look into this [article](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files) and see a test-based result for reading text files in c#. Using steams or the file class should base on your needs and the data you are trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Reading the content line by line takes to long", what do you mean? How are you actually reading the content?

However, more than anything else, let's take a step back and look at the idea of loading 1 GB of data into a ListView.

Personally you should use an `IEnumerable` to read the file, for example:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
{

}
```

But more importantly you should implement **pagination** in your UI and cut down what's visible and what's loaded immediately. This will cut down your resource use massively and make sure you have a usable UI. You can use IEnumerable methods such as [`Skip()` and `Take()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359496/array-copy-vs-skip-and-take-in-c-sharp), which are effective at using your resources effectively (i.e. not loading unused data).

You wouldn't need to use any extra threads either (aside from the background thread + UI thread), but I will suggest using MVVM and INotifyPropertyChanged to skip worrying about threading altogether.